# Determining a plane's equation and a line through a point that is perpendicular to another line in ON system

Tags: vectors

> Let pi be a plane that contains the line $l$ with the parameter form
>   $(x,y,z)=(2,-1,3)+t(1,2,1)$. The plane contains the point $P=(1,1,0)$.
>   Determine the equation of the plane and the parameter form for a line
>   through the point $P$ that is lying on the plane pi and that is
>   perpendicular to $l$.

I'm not sure about this question, but shall I first determine a line's equation on the form **x**=**x0**+t**v**, where **x0** is the point $P$ and **v** is the vector perpendicular to the line $l$? I don't know, it's just a feeling that I have inside me. I would appreciate some guiding with thinking around this problem :P

Comment: Anyone with some idea?

Comment: Is there something wrong with this question? Something that isn't clarified to you?

Comment: I would at least appreciate that you could give me a sign that this question is not good, unsolveble or something in that way so I can be aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation for your plane $\pi$ will simply be of the form $\mathbf x = \mathbf x_0 + s\mathbf u + t\mathbf v$ (you need $2$ variables to specify a plane and only $1$ to specify a line).  Given your explicit formula for $l$, you've already got $\mathbf x_0$ and $\mathbf u$.

You can find the vector $\mathbf v$ by simply taking any point on $l$ (which is in $\pi$) and subtracting it from the vector $\vec {OP}$.  This will give another vector which is in $\pi$ as well.  You'll want to make sure that $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf u$ are not collinear.

Then to find the line, $l_2$, going through $P$ that is orthogonal to $l$ you again need an $\mathbf x_2$ and a $\mathbf u_2$.  The $\mathbf x_2$ is supplied by $\vec {OP}$, though.

As for the direction vector, you should draw a picture to verify this:
$\mathbf u_2 = [(2,1,3) - (1,1,0)] - \dfrac{[(2,1,3) - (1,1,0)]\cdot (1,2,1)}{\|(1,2,1)\|^2}(1,2,1)$

What this equation is saying is that the vector pointing from $P$ to a particular point on your line $l$ (I chose the obvious one $(2,1,3)$) minus the projection of that vector onto a vector in the same direction as $l$ (the direction vector in the equation you have for $l$ is a good choice here) is a vector orthogonal to $l$, but still in the plane.